# C# - "Dynamic" DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, datagrid, csv-import

I am trying to build a form for importing Data from CSV into a Database.
Now, I am struggling with the following tasks:

depending on the table, where the Data should be imported to, we have a number of columns in the DB:
DB_COL_AMOUNT = X

The CSV file could have a different number of "columns".
It could have more or less columns than our DB table.
CSV_COL_AMOUNT = Y

Now, I want to have a DataGridView, which should display the content of the CSV file.
This part is fine and working as expected.

If I have three "columns" in my CSV file, I will get three columns in my DataGrid - and also depending, if the CSV file has a header line or not, I will take the values of the Header as Column Header for the DataGridView.

Now, I need some magic:

I have figured out, how I could combine a ComboBox Element with the ColumnHeder of the DataGrid View - to get a selection of ColumnHeader Names.

I want this, to assign the column of the DataGridView to the column in my DB.

f.e.:

Database:

```
name | surename | birthdate | postalcode |
```

DataGridView:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
```

at this point, the structure of the CSV file could be different than the structure in our Database -> I need to specify, which column should be inserted in which column of the Table.

Now, I have the names of the Table and can do the assignment:

```
col1 => surename, col2 => name, col3 => postalcode, col4 => birthdate
```

For doing this, I have found the following Code:

```
List<string> ColumnHeaders = new List<string>();

using (SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + GetDBFile))
{
   try
   {
      dbConnection.Open();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   { }

   string SQL = "PRAGMA table_info (`contacts`)";

   using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(SQL, dbConnection))
   {
      try
      {
         SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

         while (reader.Read())
         {
            if(reader.GetString(1) != "id")
            {
               ColumnHeaders.Add(reader.GetString(1));
            }
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
   }
}

ComboBox comboBoxHeaderCell = new ComboBox();
comboBoxHeaderCell.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
comboBoxHeaderCell.Visible = true;

foreach (string Header in ColumnHeaders)
{
    comboBoxHeaderCell.Items.Add(Header);
    comboBoxHeaderCell.Text = Header;
 }

dataGridView1.Controls.Add(comboBoxHeaderCell);
comboBoxHeaderCell.Location = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true).Location;
comboBoxHeaderCell.Size = this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Size;
```

This is absolutely working fine:
IF I know, how many Columns I need to create.
But since I does not know, how many columns the DataGridView will have, until the User is importing the csv file.

Does anyone have an idea, how I could get this to work?

I've tried to insert this part

```
ComboBox comboBoxHeaderCell = new ComboBox();
comboBoxHeaderCell.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
comboBoxHeaderCell.Visible = true;

foreach (string Header in ColumnHeaders)
{
    comboBoxHeaderCell.Items.Add(Header);
    comboBoxHeaderCell.Text = Header;
 }

 dataGridView1.Controls.Add(comboBoxHeaderCell);
 comboBoxHeaderCell.Location = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true).Location;
 comboBoxHeaderCell.Size = this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Size;
```

into a for loop and counting the columnNumber of the generated DataGrid - but the selection will only be created for the first column then.

I think, I need to change the Name of the ComboBox Element, but I can't do this by using a counter-Var or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

sorry - I've found a solution directly in the answers, where I have found the solution for getting the ComboBox selection for the Column Headers.

After modifying the Code given in [this MSDN discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/61940f0d-6112-4be5-8cb3-f157123c770a/c-how-to-assign-certain-columns-of-a-datagridview-with-certain-columns-of-a-datatable-that-is?forum=winformsdatacontrols) it should work for me.